# Problem with updating the div to display the form submission performed by the user Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-reactive-forms, angular-httpclient

I want to display the submission performed by the user after the form is submitted, by hiding the form area and showing the response in that area.

So on submitting the form,I'm supposed to show a mat-spinner until the response is received from the server.

The code for component.html file is as follows:

```
  <div fxFlex [hidden]="!submitted">
    <mat-list *ngIf="feedback">
      <mat-list-item>
        <h4>Your Submission</h4>
        <p matLine>Id: {{feedback.id}}</p>
        <p matLine>First Name: {{feedback.firstname}}</p>
        <p matLine>Last Name: {{feedback.lastname}}</p>
        <p matLine>Tel. Number: {{feedback.telnum}}</p>
      </mat-list-item>

    </mat-list>

    <div [hidden]="feedback">
      <mat-spinner></mat-spinner><h4>Submitting Form</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the component.ts part is as follows:

```
   this.feedbackService.submitFeedback(this.feedback)
    .subscribe(
      feedback => (this.feedback = feedback,
      console.log(feedback))

    );
```

this is the service file

```
submitFeedback(feedback: Feedback): Observable<Feedback> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };

    return this.http.post<Feedback>(baseURL + 'feedback/', feedback, httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }
```

So problem is, when I submit the form, I am making a POST request to the server for sending the feedback. Now I want to show the feedback submitted by the user, but on clicking submit, it directly shows me the value that I have used in the form instead of using the values from the server, but after 2 seconds(I've set delay of 2 s for the server response) the same area gets updated with the values received from the server, which is the way I actually want it to work.

Now I want to avoid using the instant form values and want to wait for 2 s so that the spinner is also visible.

I suppose I explained question clearly.

Comment: Please help I'm stuck inside the loader. If you have completed this assignment, please share the  method

Comment: @NehalJaisalmeria you can check the accepted answer, I tried the same way and got it working by using the ng-template for the spinner part. Try and let me know if it works for you or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply declare a flag to hide or not this chunk of form.

```
<div fxFlex [hidden]="!submitted">

    <mat-list *ngIf="!waiting && feedback else loading">
        <mat-list-item>
        <h4>Your Submission</h4>
        <p matLine>Id: {{feedback.id}}</p>
        <p matLine>First Name: {{feedback.firstname}}</p>
        <p matLine>Last Name: {{feedback.lastname}}</p>
        <p matLine>Tel. Number: {{feedback.telnum}}</p>
        </mat-list-item>

    </mat-list>

    <ng-template #loading>
        <div>
            <mat-spinner></mat-spinner><h4>Submitting Form</h4>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

</div>
```

`ng-template` defines a template that won't be rendered by default. The rendering of `loading` (the template) will be triggered by the `*ngIf`.

The `*ngIf` evaluates a second flag.
`waiting` should be set to `true` whenever the *HTTP request* is sent, and set to `false` when the response arrives.

```
this.waiting = true;
this.feedbackService.submitFeedback(this.feedback)
    .subscribe(
      feedback => {
            this.feedback = feedback;
            console.log(feedback);
            this.waiting = false;
      }, err => this.waiting = false; // In case the HTTP request fails
);
```

Try it out.

Comment: Hi, I tried out the way you suggested, but it didn't work. Also there seems to be some issue with the "!waiting else loading" part as in console it is generating this error "ERROR TypeError: "ctx_r279.feedback is undefined""

Comment: Try using `!waiting && feedback else loading` inside the `*ngIf`